# how can i force Jformattedtextfield to add commas before every 3 digits in java

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

I have a problem with JFormattedTextField
I want a JFormattedTextField so when user type a number, it separate number with a comma
example :
user type: 1234 JFormattedTextField show 1,234
or 
user type: 123456 JFormattedTextField show 123,456
or
user type: 1234567 JFormattedTextField show 1,234,567

I try following code in KeyTypped Event
        formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();

```
    formattedTextField.setBounds(56, 159, 152, 29);


    panel_1.add(formattedTextField);

        formattedTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                  for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)                      
                  {
                      result = s.charAt(i) + result;                 
                      nDigits++;                                          
                      if (((nDigits % 3) == 0) && (i > 0))                
                      {
                          result = "," + result;
                      }
                  }

                  formattedTextField.setText(result);

});
```

everything is fine but two problem still exist
1- for example, i press 5 jformattedtextfield show me 55
i press 4 it show 44
2- when i press backspace, jformattedtextfield doesn`t delete a number and instead of this,  type a small square
for example :
i press 1  formattedtextfield show me 11
i press backspace  formattedtextfield show me 11 with a blank square

please help me .

thank you all in advance

Comment: You shouldn't alter the content of the text field because that way you're messing with the user's input and can't determine whether the user entered the comma or whether your code added it. Use a formatter instead, e.g. by refering to this [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: i can use this : formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)); but when user focusLost from formattedTextField, delimiter(commas) works. i want when user  typing  number, commas applied